# mysql_query( "CALL... multiple results

Tags: php, mysql, call

I am tapping into a service that provides zip codes tax information - there service is a bit shakey, so I want to copy their database over and run the results off my own server while using their service to just update my table. However I'm not sure I'm able to loop through multiple results with this query:

`mysql_query( "CALL zip2tax.z2t_lookup('" . $strZipCode . "','" . $strUserName . "', '" . $strUserPassword . "')" )`

I've tried setting $strZipCode to *. However I get an error from the database.

I read on MySQL that `mysql_next_result` should be the solution, however I'm unsure how to properly implement that.

Comment: Why not contact them and ask for the data in CSV format rather than trying to use their API in a manner for which it does not appear to be intended.

Comment: I'll do that. Never thought that I could just ask for the data. Haha. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't call stored procedures using php mysql you will need to use php mysqli instead

extension=php_mysqli.dll